# Stopping Score from Counting if user clicks twice

Tags: android

I am learning how to code this game and I have noticed that once the answer entered is correct one can click on the answer and still add on the score. I was wondering how can i make sure that the answer is only entered once? if the answer is true for someone to get 1 score?

```
if(answer == q.getAnswer()){
                    scoreTxt.setText("Score: "+(putScore+1));
                    correct = true;
}else if(answer != q.getAnswer()){

                setHighScore();
                scoreTxt.setText("Score: 0");
```

Comment: Disable the button `myBtn.setEnabled(false)`. Also, I hope those aren't `Strings` you are comparing with `==`

Comment: If `answer` and `q.getAnswer` are strings, you should use `answer.equals(q.getAnswer())` . Also the `else if` statement isn't necessary, if it isn't equal, it is different. So in line 4 you could use just `else{ `

Comment: Thank you all I have found a solution from Atra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're marking a bool as true. Why not use it to make sure the check can only succeed once?

```
if(answer == q.getAnswer() && !correct) {
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options. One example is disabling the button after it has been clicked in the `OnClickListener`:

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

Don't forget to enable the button once moving on to the next question (I'm assuming your game has questions and answers).